# Write Redirect Rule in routes.rb that can pass params to new URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

So i have a URL called

http://localhost:3000/insurance?utm_source=article&utm_content=driving

and now this URL needs to be redirected to this

http://localhost:3000/insurance-for-all?utm_source=article&utm_content=driving

I tried doing this in routes.rb like this

```
get '/insurance', to: redirect { |params|"/insurance-for-all?#{params.to_query}" }
```

but it doesnt work.

is there a way to redirect to new url with params still intact?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect using only `path` option then all params are gonna be sent as well:

```
get '/insurance', to: redirect(path: "/insurance-for-all")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `request` object to set the `parameters` intact.

try as per [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html)

```
get '/insurance', to: redirect { |params, request| "/insurance-for-all?#{request.params.to_query}" }
```